# Disable file autosave in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

There are two cases where Access autosaves changes:

- When the user enters data into a form, this data is autosaved to the linked table
- When the form developer modifies a query, form design view, table definition, etc. these changes are autosaved after exiting the editor

I'd like to know how to change the second point so that Access only saves the file if I hit CTRL+S, similar to Word and Excel.

Though Access does ask if I want to save changes when I exit (for example) the form design view, the only way to test changes is to exit design view, which saves the file and clears the undo button. It can be very inconvenient because I have to undo everything manually if I want to revert changes.

I've found threads discussing older versions of Access, but nothing for Access 2013. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms, Reports, and Queries can be tested without saving - just switch view.

Tables cannot. If you wish to check out design changes, first create a backup of the database or at least the table.